# setuptools and pip did not properly package and install module respectively

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

I packaged and installed my test module using setuptools and pip:

```
pip install pyautomate/
```

There were no errors encountered during the process and on the commandline, it says 'Successfully installed pyautomate'. However when I tried to use the 'say_hello' method/function of the pyautomate module, I got this AttributeError:

```
>>> import pyautomate
>>> pyautomate.say_hello
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    pyautomate.say_hello
     AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'say_hello'
```

Here's the directory structure of my package:

[image]

Here's my setup.py:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
setup(
    name='pyautomate',
    version="1.0.0",
    packages=find_packages(),
    install_requires = ['suds','shodan',]
)
```

Here's my pyautomate.py:

```
import os, sys
import suds, shodan

def say_hello(self, msg):
    print "Message from PyAutomate: %s" % msg
```

Is there something I'm lacking here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does pyautomate support your Python version?

Comment: thanks for the comment but i don't get your question... pyautomate is the test module i'm packaging/installing